# Phonegap RSS Feed in Xcode not working

Tags: xcode, rss, cordova

Recently I was researching how to add an RSS Feed in Phonegap and I used a tutorial from Raymond Camden; it worked great on my browser, so I just decided to put it into xcode, but I ran into a problem; there was no content on the page :(

This is what the simulator looked like:

http://bit.ly/rMkwxL

So I thought it was a problem w/ linking to the main.js file, so i just included the javascript in the header, but still nothing. This is what the Xcode console looks like as of right now:

http://bit.ly/uY0Xmb

Do you know what I can do to make this work on Xcode?

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
    <head> 
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/themes/theme.min.css" />
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile-1.0.min.css" />
            <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.mobile-1.0.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="js/phonegap-1.2.0.js"></script>



                <script type="text/javascript">

                    $.ajaxSetup({
                                error:function(x,e,errorThrown) {
                                console.log(x.getStatusCode());
                                $("#status").prepend("Error!");     
                                }
                                });

                    //EDIT THESE LINES
                    //Title of the blog
                    var TITLE = "ColdFusion Jedi";
                    //RSS url
                    var RSS = "http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.run?_id=cd8204ba72b3220a8278b1c0665cb7c2&_render=rss";
                    //Stores entries
                    var entries = [];
                    var selectedEntry = "";

                    //listen for detail links
                    $(".contentLink").live("click", function() {
                                           selectedEntry = $(this).data("entryid");
                                           });

                    //Listen for main page
                    $("#mainPage").live("pageinit", function() {
                                        //Set the title
                                        $("h1", this).text(TITLE);

                                        $.get(RSS, {}, function(res, code) {
                                              entries = [];
                                              var xml = $(res);
                                              var items = xml.find("item");
                                              $.each(items, function(i, v) {
                                                     entry = { 
                                                     title:$(v).find("title").text(), 
                                                     link:$(v).find("link").text(), 
                                                     description:$.trim($(v).find("description").text())
                                                     };
                                                     entries.push(entry);
                                                     });

                                              //now draw the list
                                              var s = '';
                                              $.each(entries, function(i, v) {
                                                     s += '<li><a href="'+v.link+'">'+v.title+'</a></li>';
                                                     });
                                              $("#linksList").html(s);
                                              $("#linksList").listview("refresh");
                                              });

                                        });

                    //Listen for the content page to load
                    $("#contentPage").live("pageshow", function(prepage) {
                                           //Set the title
                                           $("h1", this).text(entries[selectedEntry].title);
                                           var contentHTML = "";
                                           contentHTML += entries[selectedEntry].description;
                                           contentHTML += '<p/><a href="'+entries[selectedEntry].link + '">Read Entry on Site</a>';
                                           $("#entryText",this).html(contentHTML);
                                           });



                    </script>
</head> 
<body> 

<div data-role="page" id="mainPage">

    <div data-role="header">
        <h1></h1>
    </div>

    <div data-role="content">  
        <div id="status"></div>  
        <ul id="linksList" data-role="listview" data-inset="true"></ul>
    </div>

    <div data-role="footer">
        <h4>SimpleBlog by Raymond Camden</h4>
    </div>


</div>

<div data-role="page" id="contentPage">

    <div data-role="header">
        <a href="#mainPage" data-rel="back">Home</a>
        <h1></h1>
    </div>

    <div data-role="content" id="entryText">
    </div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to add the host in PhoneGap.plist under the "ExternalHosts" key. Wildcards are ok. So if you are connecting to "http://phonegap.com", you have to add "phonegap.com" to the list (or use the wildcard "*.phonegap.com" which will match subdomains as well).

Comment: Am I adding the right domains to my p.list? I am using yahoo pipes to get an RSS feed, so I added (*pipes.yahoo.com) but it still didn't work... any ideas? –

Comment: Use wildard (asterix). ex.: *.yahoo.com